# Android file transfer without USB cable, pulling out the microSD card, or using 3rd party apps

Tags: networking, file-transfer

My android phone's charging port died, so I am looking for a *semi-convenient* way to transfer files without [using any 3rd party apps](https://superuser.com/a/558301/207006). Is it possible?

I already have an SMB share configured on my NAS, and a couple Windows computers. I have a WiFi network and a Bluetooth radio in my pc, but I'd much rather not use the latter as I've only seen abysmal transfer speeds from it.

P.S. I can still transfer files with the microSD card, but accessing it is onerous.

<sub>Fortunately, wireless charging still works on my Samsung Galaxy S8+</sub>

Comment: You don't want to use ES File exp or any 3rd party?

Answer (score 1):

## Bluetooth (Phone to PC)

Enable Bluetooth (BT) on both devices, tick the checkbox on phone to make it visible (Phone BT settings), pair phone to PC (PC BT Settings, add new device).

On Phone, View files in file explorer, if possible zip them, then share, *send via bluetooth*

On PC, run `fsquirt`, recieve files

On Phone, select your PC, and wait for the transfer to happen.

*Tip: Laptops generally sit on their BT radios*

*Note: Bluetooth speeds vary depending on devices - a colleague's S10 transfers faster than my J7P*

## Google Drive (Phone to PC via Cloud)

This involves google drive or any other cloud storage provider as a middleman. Suitable if you have a Hi-Speed internet connection

## Files By Google (Phone to Phone)

*Note: This requires a second Android Phone, and assumes both came installed with Files (by google) - Mine did*

On both phones, open Files, and go to Share

Follow the steps to setup your name and send files!

Comment: I've been pretty much using the *via Cloud* method, but my asymmetric internet connection limits the use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Phone to PC could be FTP which NEEDS third-party apps. Also, you can set up a network and turn on wifi-hotspot on PC. then access the network by entering the PC's IPV4 at chrome and accessing the HDD. you can Also use Upload and Download things like Google drive and Uploadboy. Furthermore, you can use remote control apps like Teamviewer or Anydesk. Bluetooth is not recommended because it is hardly slow and exhausting. Personally I love FTP because it is safe and fast. You can use Easyshare app to Use FTP too.

But The best is to repair your charging socket ;)

Comment: Please elaborate on the wifi-hotspot part, and remove the rest.

Comment: As I said, turn wifi hotspot on, connect to it on the pc, then go on change adaptor settings and find your PC's IPV4 there (Google it if you don't know how). type the ip in your phone on a browser. And you get access to every folder that is SHARED on your pc. You can share folders by right clicking on them, going to properties, sharing tab and clicking on the share button.

Comment: My question specifies the phone needs to be able to send files to the folder on the pc. If would please update your answer accordingly? I know how to configure SMB shares on my pc.